# Common variables for multiple modules

Tags: terraform

Is this the right way to share variables across modules or am I doing it wrong?

In a base module I add a variable:

```
variable "aws_region" {
  description = "Region to use"
  default     = "eu-west-1"
}
```

Then I expose it using `output`:

```
output "AwsRegion" {
  value = var.aws_region
}
```

Then in the module I want to use it from, I import the base module and refer to it:

```
module "base" {
  source = "../base"
}

provider "aws" {
  version = "~> 2.37"
  region  = module.base.AwsRegion
}
```

Is there a way to define the variable and export it as output in one go? Does Terraform have the concept of access modifiers? It would be great to be able to do `public variable` or `output variable`...

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not really sure what you are asking.  You've shown a module that has only a variable and an output that echoes back the value of that variable, which is not really a useful module: unless obtaining the default value `eu-west-1` is the purpose, this module would never return any value that the calling module doesn't already know. Can you edit the question to say a little more about the underlying problem you are trying to solve, independently of the way you've tried to solve it with Terraform?

Comment: @MartinAtkins - thank you for your comment... Sorry, I am very new to terraform. All I want to do is share variables across modules...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not positive it's the best way, but I've been passing them in at the main.tf file. By doing this I can see the new variables being defined as well as the values that are populating the modules' variables.

```
module "linuxvm" {
  source = "./linuxvm"
  vmprefix = var.prefix
  resourcegroup = azurerm_resource_group.main.name
  location = azurerm_resource_group.main.location
  vmos = var.os
  password = var.vmpassword
  subnetid = module.network.subnetid
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it... How does that differ from what I am doing already?

Comment: The difference I see is I'm passing the variables into the module and not leveraging existing variables in the module scope.

Within the module I'm referencing the variable as `var.vmprefix` instead of `module.ModuleName.prefix`. IMO this makes it explicit what variables are needed vs having to browse the module files for module.x.value to see the relationship.

If that's what you're doing I apologize. I'm a little confused as well.